# Bash: Filling multiple arrays from file on string matching

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I know such questions have been answered several times but I believe my case is a bit more complicated. I have an input file containing this:

```
 blabla bla
 TimeGenerated 13:13:13
 some text
 some more text
 AccountName Joe
 bla bla
 ObjectName d:\dir\
 AccessType 0x444
 bla text
 blabla bla
 TimeGenerated 13:13:15
 some text
...
```

and so on, repeating the similar pattern.
My task would be to collect AccountNames, ObjectNames and AccessTypes variables into 3 arrays, e.g. users[], objects[], types[]. I don't need to care of irrelevant lines. The solution must be elegant and fast. First I thought I'd try something like

```
while read line;do
 if [[ "$line" == 'AccountName*' ]] ... then put that into array...
 if [[ "$line" == 'ObjectName*' ]] ...  then put that into array...
```

but I think it would be too ugly. There must be a far better way. I was thinking about some lightning fast

```
 awk '/AccountName/ {print $2}' logfile  ....
   ...
```

but I have no idea how to use this output efficiently. **What's more**, I need to make sure that in case the logfile contains unexpected inconsistency, e.g. a single ObjectName line somehow disappeared from between AccountName and AccessType or its value is missing, the relevant array element gets a static string, e.g. "error".

Comment: Can you tell us what you plan to do with those bash arrays? It might be easier to do everything in awk and skip bash altogether depending on what further processing you need to do with these values.  Also, you mention a specific case that needs to be handled (unexpected missing value) --- it's important to include such cases in your sample input!

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The purpose of the arrays is to generate several difficult statistics for each user so I definitely need those arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/AccountName/ { count++; user[count] = $2; object[count] = "error"; type[count] = "error" }
/ObjectName/ { object[count] = $2 }
/AccessType/ { type[count] = $2 }

END {
    for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        print user[i], object[i], type[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I wasn't aware of this kind of END in awk. Thanks.